# How do I make this a Futurebuilder instead of a DocumentSnapshot?

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble grasping how to implement a Futurebuilder in Flutter. I have two collections in my database (users and levels) and I need each level's information to be pulled based on the current logged in user's level. Basically I just need to grab this information from Firestore so I can use it in my widgets.

This is as far as I can get, however, but I can't figure out the last step and get it to happen before building the widgets. Right now all the data just shows as null (but it prints correctly in the logs).

```
class _LevelScreenState extends State<LevelScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User loggedInUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  var userCurrentLevel;
  var currentLevelText;
  var currentLevelTitle;
  int currentLevelSolves;
  int currentLevelFails;

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);

        // obtain users's current level
        DocumentSnapshot ds = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(_auth.currentUser.uid)
            .get();
        userCurrentLevel = ds['userlevel'].toString();
        print(userCurrentLevel);

        // obtain current level text
        DocumentSnapshot ds2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('levels')
            .doc(userCurrentLevel)
            .get();
        currentLevelText = ds2['text'];
        currentLevelTitle = ds2['title'];
        currentLevelSolves = ds2['solves'];
        currentLevelFails = ds2['fails'];
        print(currentLevelTitle);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

...
```

Comment: your `getCurrentUser` method returns a `Future` as it is an `async` function but you are not using that `Future` in any way - check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data on how to do that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. I'm using all of the data that I'm storing in the variables in my widgets, I just didn't add that giant block of code here because I felt it's irrelevant to my error.

Comment: i mean that you dont care about the returned `Future` (all you do is just calling `getCurrentUser();`) - basically it is an `async` method and you dont know when it finishes - for that you have to use that returned  `Future` in your `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

check this out, hope it helps

```
@override
void initState() {
  _userData = Firestore.instance
      .collection('user_collection')
      .where("user_id", isEqualTo: widget.userId)
      .getDocuments();
  super.initState();
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: _userData,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> userSnapShot) {
          switch (userSnapShot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            default:
              if (userSnapShot.hasError) {
                return new Text('Error: ${userSnapShot.error}');
              } else if (userSnapShot.hasData &&
                  userSnapShot.data.documents.length == 1) {
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(userSnapShot.data.docs[0]['user_name']),
                      Text(userSnapShot.data.docs[0]['user_email']),
                      Text(userSnapShot.data.docs[0]['age']),
                      Text(userSnapShot.data.docs[0]['gender']),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Couldnt't fetch user details",
                  ),
                );
              }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this to work as intended by researching Streambuilders and putting a Streambuilder inside of another one. In the body of my screen I put the first one, which grabs the current user's level, then I used that result to return the second Streambuilder. Then I render the actual widgets I want with the information from there.

```
body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc(_auth.currentUser.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
                ),
              );
            }
            return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                stream: _firestore
                    .collection('levels')
                    .doc(snapshot.data['userlevel'].toString())
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                  if (!snapshot2.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  var difficulty = (snapshot2.data['fails'].toDouble() / snapshot2.data['solves'].toDouble());
                  return SingleChildScrollView(//other content in here);
```