# Global Variable Initially Contains Random Value and then Correct Value on Hot Reload

Tags: flutter, dart

Background:
I'm creating a simple scheduling app and I've created all the basic widgets - currently, I'm working on wiring them all together.

Problem:
I'm trying to obtain the currently logged in user's information by extracting their UID, and then setting it to a global variable (String _user;) - the weird thing is the global variable is random at first, and then the correct UID is stored *only* when I do a Hot Reload.

Log on first run (_user is set to non-existent UID: "5DUn5ADZH9CVV6IhbPHH"):

`W/Firestore( 4880): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(people/5DUn5ADZH9CVV6IhbPHH) failed:`

Log after Hot Reload (_user is set to existing UID: "qsEtZLxGBRe4abh5HgSp6U21rtS2"):

`W/Firestore( 4880): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(people/qsEtZLxGBRe4abh5HgSp6U21rtS2) failed:`

I've been debugging this for hours now and have no clue as to why this behavior is happening.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: WelcomePage(),
));

String _user;
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String getUser = getCurrentUID().toString();
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('people')
            .document(_user)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (checkRole(snapshot.data) == "employee") {
                  return EmployeeWidget();
              }
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  _user = user.uid;
  return user.uid;
}
```

Comment: Initial ID probably belongs to an automatically generated **anonymous** user.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getCurrentUID() from within your build method. Your build method will run multiple times. Make your home widget stateful and call getCurrentUID() from inside initState. It will then be called only once.

For code, you could look at the answer to this SO question that looks very similar to your problem: [How do I make this a Futurebuilder instead of a DocumentSnapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734931/how-do-i-make-this-a-futurebuilder-instead-of-a-documentsnapshot) Basically, do your database calls in initState and await the results in your build method using FutureBuilder or using an isLoading flag and progress indicator until the db call completes.

Comment: Did this answer your question?